# External protocol requests not working in IE 11 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, web

I have an external protocol request set up that works in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE 11 on windows 8, but not on windows 7. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your registered application's name is longer than 32 characters it will not work in Windows 7 in IE 11.

That doesn't seem to be well documented anywhere but shortening the name of the registry key and the part after URL down to 32 or less characters causes it to behave as you would expect.

E.g. application.somename.anothername will not work but application.somename.anothernam will.